# Relationships are (null) when -awakeFromInsert message received by new object in NSOrderedSet

Tags: core-data, nsmanagedobject, nsarraycontroller

The following `-awakeFromInsert` implementation sets properties of new objects instantiated by array controllers in a UI when the user presses an add button:

```
- (void)awakeFromInsert
{
    [super awakeFromInsert];
    NSLog(@"Adding perceptron %ld to layer %ld", self.indexInLayer, self.layer.indexInNetwork);
    NSLog(@"New perceptron added to layer %@", self.layer );
    // more code here to do the configuration
}
```

The problem is that the `self.parent` relationship of the new object is not set when `-awakeFromInsert` is called (it is nil) so I can't use it to access the parent object (for example how many childs there are or what index the new object is).

Output of the above code:

```
2012-12-17 21:36:39.309 MLPManager[98112:403] Adding perceptron 0 to layer 0
2012-12-17 21:36:39.309 MLPManager[98112:403] New perceptron added to layer (null)
```

I'm pretty sure that the new objects are being connected up correctly because the `indexInLayer` method works perfectly when the `UITableView` calls it to add indexes of the objects to the view:

```
- (NSUInteger)indexInLayer
{
    NSUInteger index = [self.layer.perceptrons indexOfObject:self];
    //NSLog(@"indexInLayer returning %ld", index );
    return index;
}
```

My data model has three entities: Network, Layer, Perceptron arranged as ordered sets and connected to the next by to-many relationships (i.e. Parent - Child - Grandchild).  My UI has three array controllers and three `UITableViews`.  I've set it up so that the Child array controller only contains the children of the selected Parent, and the Grandchild array controller only contains the grandchildren of the selected Child.  When I add childs or grandchilds to these arraycontrollers they are automatically set as children of the currently selected parent.  That all works fine.

At what point is `self.layer` set by the UI?  Can someone confirm that this is occurring after `-awakeFromInsert`?  And if so, how am I supposed to configure a new object if I can't do it from within `-awakeFromInsert`?  I note that the Apple documentation for `-awakeFromInsert` says it is "invoked automatically by the Core Data framework when the receiver is first inserted into a managed object context."

The reason I need information on the layer object and other parts of the data structure is that I need to automatically instantiate various other objects (weights which are children of perceptrons) at the same time as the new perceptron object.  Should I be using `-awakeFromInsert` for these kind of tasks?

Answer (score 0):

First, there appears to be coupling in your code between model (`NSManagedObject`) and view (`UITableView`) objects. That is not recommended according to the model-view-controller design pattern.

`layer` and `indexInLayer` are not standard attributes of `NSManagedObject` so I assume these are attributes in your entity. As an alternative to doing the setup in `awakeFromInsert`, I wonder if you can instead implement your own setter methods for your attributes so that you can do the necessary work at the time the required data is available.

If you choose to implement your own setter methods, you need to follow Apple's guidance in the [Managed Object Accessor Methods](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdAccessorMethods.html) documentation, specifically:

> You must ensure that you invoke the relevant access and change
>   notification methods (willAccessValueForKey:, didAccessValueForKey:,
>   willChangeValueForKey:, didChangeValueForKey:,
>   willChangeValueForKey:withSetMutation:usingObjects:, and
>   didChangeValueForKey:withSetMutation:usingObjects:).

I do not know why `layer` and `indexInLayer` are not usable in your `awakeFromInsert` method; it's possible you need to solve that problem instead.